# vertical & horizontal lines in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I do not quite understand why I am unable to create horizontal and vertical lines at specified limits. I would like to bound the data by this box. However, the sides do not seem to comply with my instructions. Why is this?

```
# CREATING A BOUNDING BOX
# BOTTOM HORIZONTAL
plt.axhline(y=.4, xmin=0.25, xmax=0.402, linewidth=2, color = 'k')
# RIGHT VERTICAL
plt.axvline(x=0.402, ymin=0.4, ymax = 0.615, linewidth=2, color='k')
# LEFT VERTICAL
plt.axvline(x=0.1, ymin=0.58, ymax = 0.79, linewidth=2, color='k')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 180, accepted):

The pyplot functions you are calling, [`axhline()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axhline) and [`axvline()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axvline) draw lines that span a portion of the axis range, regardless of coordinates. The parameters `xmin` or `ymin` use value 0.0 as the minimum of the axis and 1.0 as the maximum of the axis.

Instead, use `plt.plot((x1, x2), (y1, y2), 'k-')` to draw a line from the point (x1, y1) to the point (x2, y2) in color k. See [`pyplot.plot`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot).

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axhline <- documentation.  You should edit your answer to include this link

Comment: Another solution to plot horizontal and vertical lines is to use [`hlines`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hlines) or [`vlines`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.vlines), respectively, as this is more trivial than a regular `plot` i.m.o.

Answer (score 33):

This may be a common problem for new users of Matplotlib to draw vertical and horizontal lines. In order to understand this problem, you should be aware that [different coordinate systems exist in Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html).

The method [axhline](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axhline.html) and [axvline](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axvline.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.axvline) are used to draw lines at the **axes coordinate**. In this coordinate system, coordinate for the bottom left point is (0,0), while the coordinate for the top right point is (1,1), regardless of the data range of your plot. Both the parameter `xmin` and `xmax` are in the range [0,1].

On the other hand, method [hlines](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.hlines.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.hlines) and [vlines](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.vlines.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.vlines) are used to draw lines at the **data coordinate**. The range for `xmin` and `xmax` are the in the range of data limit of x axis.

Let's take a concrete example,

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 5, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, y)
ax.axhline(y=0.5, xmin=0.0, xmax=1.0, color='r')
ax.hlines(y=0.6, xmin=0.0, xmax=1.0, color='b')

plt.show()
```

It will produce the following plot:
[image]

The value for `xmin` and `xmax` are the same for the `axhline` and `hlines` method. But the length of produced line is different.

Answer (score 16):

If you want to add a bounding box, use a rectangle:

```
ax = plt.gca()
r = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((.5, .5), .25, .1, fill=False)
ax.add_artist(r)
```

[`Rectangle` doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Rectanglehttp://)