# Vertical line not respecting min,max limits (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Minimal working example of the issue:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

horiz_line = 0.0005
vert_line = 110
x_data = [10, 30, 50, 70, 90, 110, 130, 150, 170, 190, 210, 230, 250, 270, 290, 310, 330, 350, 370, 390, 410, 430, 450, 470, 490]
y_data = [0.0074999999999999997, 0.011875, 0.0057812499999999999, 0.0036458333333333334, 0.0020312500000000001, 0.0013125000000000001, 0.00098958333333333342, 0.00089285714285714283, 0.00074218750000000001, 0.00093749999999999997, 0.00071874999999999999, 0.00088068181818181821, 0.00078125000000000004, 0.0004807692307692308, 0.00055803571428571425, 0.00083333333333333339, 0.00066406250000000005, 0.00069852941176470592, 0.00059027777777777778, 0.00059210526315789478, 0.00062500000000000001, 0.0007291666666666667, 0.00068181818181818187, 0.00059782608695652171, 0.00053385416666666663]

fig = plt.figure() # create the top-level container

# horizontal line
plt.axhline(y=horiz_line, xmin=0, xmax=max(x_data), color='red', zorder=1)

# vertical line
plt.axvline(x=vert_line, ymin=0, ymax=max(y_data), color='red', zorder=2)

plt.scatter(x_data, y_data, s=150, color='blue', zorder=3)

plt.show()
```

Which gives me this:

[image]

Notice the little red vertical line at `x=110`. Why is it not respecting the min & max limits I set with `ymin=0, ymax=max(y_data)` (which should be `min=0` ; `max=0.011875`)?

Comment: Because the coordinates in the `axhline` and `axvline` method calls are _Axes coordinates_, not _data coordinates_.

Comment: is it in a different coordinate space?

Comment: @nordev Oh I see that now. I also found this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930328/vertical-horizontal-lines-in-matplotlib?rq=1) right after I asked this one. Care to format your comment as an answer so I can mark it as solved?

Comment: It is odd how questions _seem_ to come in bunches (that is two or more questions with basically the same problem with in a day of each other, but no similar questions in the more distant recent past).  Probably just the brain finding patterns when the don't exist.

Comment: That **is** odd. I just realized the question I point to was asked only 18 hours ago o.O

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It seems you want the functionality provided by [`hlines`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hlines) and [`vlines`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.vlines) rather than [`axhline`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axhline) and [`axvline`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axvline), as the two latter uses the [*Axes coordinate system*](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html#axes-coordinates), while `hlines` and `vlines` use the [*data coordinate system*](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html#data-coordinates).

So your code should be

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

horiz_line = 0.0005
vert_line = 110
x_data = [10, 30, 50, 70, 90, 110, 130, 150, 170, 190, 210, 230, 250, 270, 290, 310, 330, 350, 370, 390, 410, 430, 450, 470, 490]
y_data = [0.0074999999999999997, 0.011875, 0.0057812499999999999, 0.0036458333333333334, 0.0020312500000000001, 0.0013125000000000001, 0.00098958333333333342, 0.00089285714285714283, 0.00074218750000000001, 0.00093749999999999997, 0.00071874999999999999, 0.00088068181818181821, 0.00078125000000000004, 0.0004807692307692308, 0.00055803571428571425, 0.00083333333333333339, 0.00066406250000000005, 0.00069852941176470592, 0.00059027777777777778, 0.00059210526315789478, 0.00062500000000000001, 0.0007291666666666667, 0.00068181818181818187, 0.00059782608695652171, 0.00053385416666666663]

fig = plt.figure() # create the top-level container

# horizontal line
plt.hlines(y=horiz_line, xmin=0, xmax=max(x_data), color='red', zorder=1)

# vertical line
plt.vlines(x=vert_line, ymin=0, ymax=max(y_data), color='red', zorder=2)

plt.scatter(x_data, y_data, s=150, color='blue', zorder=3)

plt.show()
```

[image]