# Plotting phase changes in matplotlib/pandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I'd like to be able to use matplotlib & pandas to create graphs based on dynamic data from a google spreadsheet. I've been successful in querying the spreadsheet with gspread, saving to csv, and plotting, but haven't been able to come up with a workaround for phase change lines. Here is an example of format: http://www.ebbp.org/course_outlines/critical_appraisal/pdfs/SSRD-1.gif The phase change lines would need to fall between x-axis values, whether the scale is in dates or sessions. Data paths also cannot connect across the phase change lines.

Here is the code I'm currently working with

```
  import gspread
    import csv
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import getpass


    usernm = raw_input("Enter Username")
    pw = getpass.getpass("Enter password for user %s: " % usernm)
    gc = gspread.login(usernm, pw)

    client = raw_input("Which client profile would you like to see?")

    wks = gc.open(client)

    for i, worksheet in enumerate(wks.worksheets()):
        filename = client + '-worksheet' + str(i) + '.csv'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerows(worksheet.get_all_values())

    df = pd.read_csv('CSV FILE HERE', sep=',')        

    df.plot(x='Date', grid=False, marker='o', color='k', title='Hello')

    plt.show()
```

I moved from using google's visualization API to python and matplotlib because I thought it would have more functionality and features to accomplish this, but there's no way I can think of. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to do this in the future here's the thread I found to be helpful:[vertical & horizontal lines in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930328/vertical-horizontal-lines-in-matplotlib)

Here is a workable solution:

```
plt.axvline(x=2.5, ymin=0, ymax = 1.0, linewidth=1, color='k')
```

Still trying to figure out how to not have data paths connect across (other than interpolate nulls)

Answer (score 0):

Addressing your last comment in your answer, let's say that you have the following changes of phase

```
changes = [20,35,55]
```

you can plot the unconnected parts like this

```
first = 0
for c in changes:
    plt.plot(x[first:c], y[first:c])
    first = c+1
plt.plot(x[first:],y[first:])
```

Comment: This looks like it would do exactly what I want, but I must be implementing it incorrectly. I'm getting an x is not defined error. Any suggestions? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't speak Pandas, so I tried to express the concept you should use using generic names (`x` and `y`) and the generic `pyplot` API. If you can't translate this concept in a Pandas <del>frame</del> context, you should ask for someone else's help because I'm not a Pandas man...