# Disconnect (or re-color) lines at specific data points in pandas/matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I'd like to be able to be able to remove the line connecting a datapath at certain points. (Or turn it white against a white background.)

Here's my previous thread for reference: [Previous Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006581/plotting-phase-changes-in-matplotlib-pandas/27007336?noredirect=1#comment42560743_27007336)

In my previous thread I wished to create a vertical line between data points and succeeded in doing so, now I just need to be able to remove the segment. Any ideas?

Comment: show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: `plt.axvline(x=location, ymin=0, ymax=1.0, linewidth=11, color='w')
plt.axvline(x=location, ymin=0, ymax=1.0, linewidth=1, color='k')` This is what I have so far, the only way I could figure was to create the black phase change line on top of a thicker white one based on user input of location. Not a very good solution I'm afraid.

Comment: I think something like this might work, but I can't figure out how to implement. [Example of multicolored line](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multicolored_line.html)