# draw line or color area when exceeding a range in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to draw a line or color an area at a specific limit

for example color or draw line at/above 10 and at/under -10

like this examples

[image]
[image]

when coloring the area, the color should be transparent

Comment: Would [this](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) work for the lines? Here's [another](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16930526/5012922) explanation. A bounding box would probably work for the color

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `axhline` or `fill_between` functions,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#Define min and max line
minline = -10
maxline = 10

#Generate dummy plotting data
x = np.arange(0.0, 2, 0.01)
y1 = 25*np.sin(2*np.pi*x)-10
y2 = 30*np.sin(4*np.pi*x)-10
maxy=max(y1.max(),y2.max())
miny=min(y1.min(),y2.min())

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,1)

#Plot dummy data
for ax in axs:
    ax.plot(x,y1,'b')
    ax.plot(x,y2,'g')

#Draw lines
axs[0].axhline(y=minline,color='r')
axs[0].axhline(y=maxline,color='r')

#Draw filled regions
axs[1].fill_between(x,minline,miny,color='r',alpha=0.3)
axs[1].fill_between(x,maxline,maxy,color='r',alpha=0.3)

plt.show()
```

which gives,

[image]