# How to draw a precision-recall curve with interpolation in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn, precision-recall

I have drawn a precision-recall curve using `sklearn` `precision_recall_curve`function and `matplotlib` package. For those of you who are familiar with precision-recall curve you know that some scientific communities only accept it when its interpolated, similar to this example [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/evaluation-of-ranked-retrieval-results-1.html). Now my question is if any of you know how to do the interpolation in python? I have been searching for a solution for a while now but with no success! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Solution:** Both solutions by @francis and @ali_m are correct and together solved my problem. So, assuming that you get an output from the `precision_recall_curve` function in `sklearn`, here is what I did to plot the graph:

```
precision["micro"], recall["micro"], _ = precision_recall_curve(y_test.ravel(),scores.ravel())
pr = copy.deepcopy(precision[0])
rec = copy.deepcopy(recall[0])
prInv = np.fliplr([pr])[0]
recInv = np.fliplr([rec])[0]
j = rec.shape[0]-2
while j>=0:
    if prInv[j+1]>prInv[j]:
        prInv[j]=prInv[j+1]
    j=j-1
decreasing_max_precision = np.maximum.accumulate(prInv[::-1])[::-1]
plt.plot(recInv, decreasing_max_precision, marker= markers[mcounter], label=methodNames[countOfMethods]+': AUC={0:0.2f}'.format(average_precision[0]))
```

And these lines will plot the interpolated curves if you put them in a for loop and pass it the data of each method at each iteration. Note that this will not plot the non-interpolated precision-recall curves.

Comment: Please do ***not*** put a solution into the question. Write an Answer for that, if you feel the information should be shared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A backward iteration can be performed to remove the increasing parts in `precision`. Then, vertical and horizontal lines can be plotted as specified in the answer of Bennett Brown to [vertical & horizontal lines in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930328/vertical-horizontal-lines-in-matplotlib) .

Here is a sample code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#just a dummy sample
recall=np.linspace(0.0,1.0,num=42)
precision=np.random.rand(42)*(1.-recall)
precision2=precision.copy()
i=recall.shape[0]-2

# interpolation...
while i>=0:
    if precision[i+1]>precision[i]:
        precision[i]=precision[i+1]
    i=i-1

# plotting...
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(recall.shape[0]-1):
    ax.plot((recall[i],recall[i]),(precision[i],precision[i+1]),'k-',label='',color='red') #vertical
    ax.plot((recall[i],recall[i+1]),(precision[i+1],precision[i+1]),'k-',label='',color='red') #horizontal

ax.plot(recall,precision2,'k--',color='blue')
#ax.legend()
ax.set_xlabel("recall")
ax.set_ylabel("precision")
plt.savefig('fig.jpg')
fig.show()
```

And here is a result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also wrote the solution adapted to the output of the precision_recall_curve in sklearn.

Answer (score 12):

**@francis's** solution can be vectorized using [`np.maximum.accumulate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

recall = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, num=42)
precision = np.random.rand(42)*(1.-recall)

# take a running maximum over the reversed vector of precision values, reverse the
# result to match the order of the recall vector
decreasing_max_precision = np.maximum.accumulate(precision[::-1])[::-1]
```

You can also use [`plt.step`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.step) to get rid of the `for` loop used for plotting:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.hold(True)
ax.plot(recall, precision, '--b')
ax.step(recall, decreasing_max_precision, '-r')
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution helped me to adapt @francis's code to the output of the precision_recall_curve function. I wrote the solution. +1, thanks.