# Split pandas dataframe conditionally to plot with different colors

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have pandas dataframe with pair of values and like to color code it conditionally such as

`df.plot(kind='scatter', ax=ax1, x='a', y='b', c=np.where(['a']>0.5, 'r', 'g']))`

But not getting anywhere. Applying same condition on both `a` and `b` is ultimate objective. Any lead is appreciative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Demo:

```
In [50]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100, 2), columns=['x','y'])

In [51]: df.head()
Out[51]:
          x         y
0  0.376715  0.209387
1  0.633065  0.212350
2  0.538783  0.883493
3  0.753707  0.983746
4  0.135703  0.840134    

In [52]: df.plot.scatter(x='x', y='y', s=20, c=np.where(df['y']>0.5, 'r', 'g'))
Out[52]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x1078f4e0>
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

> is it possible to nest two conditions in there such as
>   `c=np.where(df_AA['a']>0.5 and df_AA['b']<0.5, 'r', 'b')`

```
In [70]: df.plot.scatter(x='x', y='y', s=20, c=np.where((df['x']>0.5) & (df['y']<0.5), 'r', 'g'), grid=True)
Out[70]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xc166dd8>
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible to nest two conditions in there such as `c=np.where(df['a']>0.5 and df['b']<0.5, 'r', 'b')` ?

Comment: one last thing, can we break the grid into 4 quadrants?

Comment: @Ibe, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930328/vertical-horizontal-lines-in-matplotlib ;-)

Comment: i thought it will be easy to nest `np.where` but proving to be difficult. I also want to red color value `(df['x']<0.5) & (df['y']>0.5)` on same plot. including this with another `&` is throwing error

Comment: @Ibe, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Split data in 4 quadrants. Both columns are from 0 to 1. Color code all data depending on which quadrant they fall in: ul and lr colored red and ur and ll colored blue

Comment: @Ibe, ‘((df['x']>0.5) & (df['y']<0.5)) | ((df[“x”]<0.5) & (df[“y”]>0.5))’? I’m using phone now, so you might need to fix the syntax...

Comment: i was trying it without pipe. its working now with pipe. thanks

Comment: How do I do this but for a line plot instead?