# Draw a line with matplotlib using the axis coordinate system

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a vertical line that spans the entire y axis located for example in the x=.25 position of the **x axis**, not the **data axis**.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50444666/1391441) (which is apparently not entirely accurate) the `axhline,axvline` functions would draw a horizontal/vertical line in the *axes coordinates*, as shown in:

> The method axhline and axvline are used to draw lines at the **axes coordinate**

But this does not seem to work. The [axhline docs say](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axhline.html):

> y position in **data coordinates** of the horizontal line.

and sure enough, the code given in the answer above displays:

[image]

Compare with the old plot shown in the mentioned answer (code below):

[image]

Did this change recently or am I missing something very obvious? If it did change, how would I draw a line in the axes coordinate now?

I'm using Python 3.7.3 and `matplotlib` 3.1.0.

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 5, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, y)
ax.axhline(y=0.5, xmin=0.0, xmax=1.0, color='r')
ax.hlines(y=0.6, xmin=0.0, xmax=1.0, color='b')

plt.show()
```

Comment: it depends on your `min` `max` parameters, no?

Comment: axvline did not intentionally change behaviour. The question does not allow to see what's undesired.

Comment: I infer from the linked question that since the functions use coordintate system, min=0 and max =1 should span the full range of the axis, but now it's only drawing a line from values x=0 to x=1, while expected is x=0, x=5

Comment: @Yuca no, the question is why `axhline` does not plot a line in the **axes coordinates**, not the **data coordinates**, as I believe it should. IOBE see updated question please.

Comment: I just verified. The documentation is correct. The linked question's answer may be a bit misleading, but also correct. The min/max coordinates are in axes coordinates, but the x/y is in data coordinates.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest but something necessarily changed. I am running the exact same code shown in the linked answer, but getting a different plot.

Comment: You're right, the image in that answer is wrong. The red line is off - it's neither at `y=0.5` in data- nor in axes coordinates. So I think one can assume it to be generated by a code that is not shown  in the answer. But if you replace the wrong image with the one you get with that code, the answer is correct, rigth? It might make sense to just edit that answer.

Comment: Yes, I believe that answer remains correct if we edit the plot (this line "*The method axhline and axvline are used to draw lines at the axes coordinate.*" would need to be corrected too I think, right?). But my question here remains: how do I plot a line in the *axes coordinate*?

Comment: You mean a line where both x *and* y coordinates are in axes coordinates?

Comment: Yes. If I wanted to plot a vertical line that spanned the entire y axis located in the `x=.25` position of the *x axis*, not the *data axis*. How would I do that?

Comment: Ok, I answered that question below; maybe you want to edit your question with what you really wanted to know, such that Q&A are coherent?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering the question

> If I wanted to plot a vertical line that spanned the entire y axis located in 
>   the x=.25 position of the x axis, not the data axis. How would I do that?

In that case both of the x coordinates of that line are `0.25` and the y coordinates are `0` for the lower end and `1` for the upper end.  The transform of the line is set to the axes coordinate system  `ax.transAxes`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set(xlim=(0.5,1.5), ylim=(-50,50))

ax.plot([0.25,0.25],[0,1], transform=ax.transAxes)

plt.show()
```