# How to plot a bar for a dictionary?

Tags: python

I want to plot a bar using matplotlib using a dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
plt.style.use('ggplot')

import numpy as np

dictionary = {0: 0, 1: 13.2, 2: 29.7, 3: 43, 4: 52}
plt.bar(list(dictionary.keys()), dictionary.values(), color='red')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y(%)')
plt.show()
```

[image]

However, I would like to get my picture like this one:

[image]

Could you please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vertical & horizontal lines in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930328/vertical-horizontal-lines-in-matplotlib); the function you want is [`axhline`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axhline.html), which the linked question provides example uses of.

Comment: @ymbirtt, it is not the case.

Comment: You're right, it looks like [`plot`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) is more what you want, though the question I flagged as a duplicate does describe how to use it in its accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could explicitly plot the black lines like so :

```
for k,v in dictionary.items(): 
    plt.plot([0,k],[v,v], color='black')
```

This code just plots a line between two points, the points being `(0,Y_n)` and `(x_n, Y_n)` for each of the bars. (`n` being the number of the bar)

**Result :**

[image: Bar graph with top lines]